# remove prefix and suffix and leave middle string

Tags: regex, powershell

```
2018-09-12_@zulire_6600287891371330821
2019-07-14_@alex_marv_660067913713308218755
```

https://regexr.com/5huq8

i am trying to remove everything before and after the central word [zuliere , alex etc] but my regex is not working.

i tried this

.*_@(.*zulire)_6.*

result i am trying to get

```
zulire
alex_marv
```

i am trying to use it in this powershell

```
Get-ChildItem -File |  # Get files
  Group-Object { $_.Name -match '@([^_]+)' } |  # Group by part before first underscore
  ForEach-Object {
    # Create directory
    $dir = New-Item -Type Directory -Name $_.Name
    # Move files there
    $_.Group | Move-Item -Destination $dir
  }
Start-Sleep -Seconds 600
```

Comment: Just `@([^_]+)` might do. Or, `(?<=@)[^_]+`

Comment: i edited the question. what if there is alex_marv instead of alex only

Comment: Then `@(.*)_\d+$` or `(?<=@).*(?=_\d+$)`

Comment: and what to do when to remove the first and last such that middle name left. i am trying to use regex in powershell such that it remove first and last string and name the folder by the middle name like [zulire] or  [alex_marv] etc.

Comment: You do not need to use `-replace`, you may use `-match`

Comment: it created a folder with "true" name. here is the powershell

Comment: Also, `$string -replace '.*@(.*)_.*', '$1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match any chars in between `@` and the last `_` followed with one or more digits:

```
$string = '2018-09-12_@zulire_6600287891371330821'
$string -match '(?<=@).*(?=_\d+$)' | Out-Null
$matches[0]
# => zulire
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iSN0Tz/1/). Details:

- `(?<=@)` - a location immediately preceded with `@`
- `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than a newline, as many as possible
- `(?=_\d+$)` - immediately followed with `_` and one or more digits till end of string.

If you insist on  a `-replace` solution use

```
$string -replace '.*@(.*)_\d+$', '$1'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iSN0Tz/2). Here,

- `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than a newline, as many as possible
- `@` - a `@` char
- `(.*)` - Group 1 (`$1`): any 0 or more chars other than a newline, as many as possible
- `_` - a `_` char
- `\d+` -  one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

**NOTE**: If there may be anything at the end but `_`, just replace `\d+$` with `.*`:

```
$string -replace '.*@(.*)_.*', '$1'
```